# Perform logic operations with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series, logical-operators

Let's have this table with binary time series as example

```
date  | name | val
25/11 |   A  | 0
24/11 |   B  | 1
22/11 |   C  | 1
21/11 |   A  | 1
21/11 |   B  | 0
 etc .....
```

Drawn as signals it would be something like this:

Perform  OR OPERATION = A || B || C

```
             ______         ____
A       _____|    |________|      

        ______         _________
B       |    |________|         

         ______     ___________
C       _|    |_____|         |_

-----------------------------    
        __________   ___________
result            |_|
```

*Let's suppose for simplification that dates are synchronized*

**Is it possible to do the logic operation directly with a MySQL query to avoid looping  ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `max()`:

```
select date, max(val)
from t
group by date;
```

Note that "and" would be `min()`.

Comment: nice trick!, not valid for "general logical operations" but really useful here

Comment: if you want other operations you probably will have to use `CASE ... WHEN ` and list all your combinations